# Localization is not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, localization, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing an app which is to be opened directly in Portuguese language and inside that app it has having the option of changing the language to English. So i have to change the language in the code . But when i tested my app in Lollipop, it is directly opening in English Language.
In all other versions except the lollipop , it is working fine. 
Can some one help me or suggest me the steps which i have to take to solve this bug.
Thanks

Here is the code which i am using for the localization.
Have some methods been "depreciated" from lollipop?

```
    public static Locale locale = new Locale("pt_BR");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    String locale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale
            .getDisplayName();
    Log.i("System out", "(LogIn)Current Language : " + locale);
```

Comment: _So i have to change the language in the code_ Please include the code.

Comment: @alanv here is the code.. plz check it out.. and let me know if somewhere i am going wrong!!

Comment: When is this code running? Is that inside of your Activity.onCreate()?

Comment: @alanv yes.. this is the method which i am calling in each activity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Due to some security issue --> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:

Language changing is not working, please try to change
*Locale locale = Locale("en_US");*
to
*Locale locale = Locale("en", "US"); //Locale locale = Locale("language", "Country")*